# Why does my VBscript RegExp Replace unexpectedly fail when replacement contains $&?

Tags: vbscript

```
DIM re2:Set re2 = New RegExp 
WITH re2
.Pattern = "dol amp"
.IgnoreCase = True
.Global = True
MsgBox .Replace("put dol amp here","ok$&done") 
' Expected: put ok$&done here
' Observed: put okdol ampdone here
END WITH
```

Expected is based on the docs:

"Regular Expression (RegExp) Object"
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yab2dx62(v=vs.84).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9z80300(v=vs.84).aspx

"Introduction to Regular Expressions (Scripting)"
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wzad2b2(v=vs.84).aspx

Contrast success here:

```
DIM re2:Set re2 = New RegExp 
WITH re2
.Pattern = "dol amp"
.IgnoreCase = True
.Global = True
MsgBox .Replace("put dol amp here","ok$ &done") 
' Expected: put ok$ &done here
' Observed: as expected
END WITH
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because in the Replace replacement string, $& is a reserved sequence having special significance, despite that the docs make no mention of this.

Workaround: PROVIDED you're happy replying on undocumented behaviour, you can escape the $& e.g.

```
DIM re2:Set re2 = New RegExp 
WITH re2
.Pattern = "dol amp"
.IgnoreCase = True
.Global = True
MsgBox .Replace("put dol amp here",Replace("ok$&done","$","$$")) 
' Expected: put ok$&done here
' Observed: as expected
END WITH
```

Observed:

[image]

Readers not happy relying on undefined behaviour, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40426225/re-the-issue-of-literal-in-regexp-replace-pattern-does-anyone-have-a-solutio

Answer (score 2):

Undocumented isn't the same as undefined. While the VBScript documentation is lacking in some points (particularly when it comes to the finer details of regular expressions), the behavior is not exactly unexpected. Microsoft has a long history of escaping characters with a special meaning by doubling them (most prominent example in VBScript are double quotes in string literals). And `&` is the common metacharacter for "the entire match" in many regular expression implementations.

If you're pressed for documentation you could take a look at the [documentation for the .Net regular expression engine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx). It's feature set is basically a superset of the features implemented in the VBScript engine.

To summarize:

- `$&` in a substitution pattern is a reference to the entire match.
- `$1`, `$2`, etc. are [backreferences](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzhdcs5c.aspx) to capturing groups.
- To get a literal `$&`, `$1`, `$2`, etc. in a replacement escape the `$` by doubling it.

Comment: "Undocumented isn't the same as undefined." The fact this behaviour is undocumented does make it undefined. 'In computer programming, undefined behavior (UB) is the result of executing computer code the behaviour of which is not prescribed by the language specification to which the code adheres, for the current state of the program (e.g. memory).' -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior

Comment: "Microsoft has a long history of escaping characters with a special meaning by doubling them .... And & is the common metacharacter for.." Take care with that guesswork. In this case, doubling & fails.

Comment: *The fact this behaviour is undocumented does make it undefined.* No. You merely fail to understand that the VBScript documentation in MSDN is not the [language specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language_specification) (which to my knowledge hasn't been published).

Comment: "You merely fail to understand that the VBScript documentation in MSDN is not the language specification". If you have any evidence there IS a language specification that makes this behaviour defined, let's see it. Until then, the behaviour remains undefined. Your guesswork as to what the language specification specification does/would say is not a definition

Comment: Search has brought me here. I'm almost a year later, but, it is not undocumented, it is bad documented. In [What's New in Windows Script 5.5](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974619.aspx) (when the `$&` was included) in the JScript section it is stated the inclusion of the *"dollar variables"*, and in the VBScript section it is stated that *"VBScript now has all the features of JScript regular expressions"*